I can't Publish an Image to Adafruit.io using Adafruit_MQTT.h
I am using ArduinoIDE on my MacBook Pro running MacOS 15.1 to install a program on an AI-Thinker ESP32 CAM.
In the program I can connect to WiFi using WifiManager to input and save the ssid and password.
Once connected I log onto to Adafruit.io using Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h and Adafruit_MQTT.h libraries.
I can Subscribe to a feeds/topic and Publish to a feeds/topic fine.
However I cannot seem to figure out how to Publish an Image taken with the ESP32 CAM.
Below is the code I use to connect to wifi, log onto Adafruit.io and Subscribe and Publish to feeds/topics.
It also shows what I am doing to Publish the Image with the log crash reports after each attempt.
I am also including the various ways that Adafruit_MQTT.h suggests for Publishing information.
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"

#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"

#include "Arduino.h"

#include <WiFiManager.h> //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "src/OV2640.h"

#include <string.h>

#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER

#include "camera_pins.h"

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <base64.h>

#define AIO_SERVER "io.adafruit.com"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT 1883 // 8883 for MQTTS
#define AIO_USERNAME "namename" //original
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define AIO_KEY "keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey"
#define MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE 18000000
long debouncing_time = 1000;
volatile unsigned long wifiResetLastMillis = 0;
bool shouldSaveConfig = false;
OV2640 cam;

long lastMsg = 0;
uint32_t z = 1;
int tripper = 1;
int cameratime = 2160000000;
WiFiManager wifiManager;
// wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(600);
WiFiClient client;

void saveConfigCallback() {
  Serial.println("Should save config");
  shouldSaveConfig = true;
}

Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt( & client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);

Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe video1 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe( & mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/video");

Adafruit_MQTT_Publish wifi = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish( & mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/wifi-connection");
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish camera1 = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish( & mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/camera");

void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;
  // Stop if already connected.
  if(mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
    mqtt.disconnect();
    Serial.print("disconnect");
  }
  
  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");
  uint8_t retries = 30;
  while((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
    Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
    Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
    mqtt.disconnect();
    delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds
    retries--;
    if(retries == 0) {
      // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
      while(1);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  wifiManager.autoConnect("LEVEL2");
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
    client.stop();
  }
  
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  // Frame parameters
  //  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 1;
  //#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  //pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //#endif
  cam.init(config);
  mqtt.subscribe( & video1);
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected3");
    delay(1000);
    MQTT_connect();
    delay(500);
    Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe * subscription;
    while((subscription = mqtt.readSubscription(3000))) {
      Serial.println("subscription");
      if(subscription == & video1) {
        Serial.print(F("Got photoonoff: "));
        Serial.println((char * ) video1.lastread);
        uint16_t sliderval = atoi((char * ) video1.lastread);
        Serial.print(tripper);
        Serial.print(tripper);
        if((sliderval == 0) && (tripper == 1)) {
          cameratime = 4000;
          long now = millis();
          Serial.print(now);
          if(now - lastMsg > cameratime) {
            camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
            fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
            if(!fb) {
              Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
              return;
            } else {
              Serial.println("Camera Captured");
            }
            size_t size = fb -> len;
            //String buffer = base64::encode((uint8_t *)fb->buf, fb->len);
            String buffer = base64::encode(fb -> buf, fb -> len);
            Serial.println(buffer);
            unsigned int length();
            Serial.println("Buffer Length: ");
            Serial.print(buffer.length());
            Serial.println("");
            if(buffer.length() > 102400) {
              Serial.println("Image size too big");
              return;
            }

Here is one way I tried to Publish Image.
        int str_len = buffer.length();
        char v[str_len + 1];
        buffer.toCharArray(v, str_len + 1);
        Serial.print(F("\nSending camera1 val"));
        Serial.print(v);
        Serial.print("...");
        if(!camera1.publish(v)) {
          Serial.println(F("Failed"));
        } else {
          Serial.print(F("OK!"));
          lastMsg = now;
          buffer = "";
        }
        tripper = 2;
        Serial.print("tripped");
        Serial.print(tripper);
      }
    }
  }

This is the crash log
14:16:24.484 -> Buffer Length: 
14:16:24.518 -> 23924
14:16:24.518 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
14:16:24.518 -> 
14:16:24.518 -> Core  0 register dump:
14:16:24.518 -> PC      : 0x40090e70  PS      : 0x00060f33  A0      : 0x800933ec  A1      : 0x3ffbad00  
14:16:24.553 -> A2      : 0x0b5cc29d  A3      : 0xb33fffff  A4      : 0x0000abab  A5      : 0x00060f23  
14:16:24.553 -> A6      : 0x00060f20  A7      : 0x0000cdcd  A8      : 0x0000cdcd  A9      : 0xffffffff  
14:16:24.553 -> A10     : 0x00000008  A11     : 0x00000001  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x40083b4c  
14:16:24.553 -> A14     : 0xcbdcc29d  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x0000001a  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
14:16:24.591 -> EXCVADDR: 0x0b5cc29d  LBEG    : 0x40085a85  LEND    : 0x40085a8d  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> Backtrace: 0x40090e6d:0x3ffbad00 0x400933e9:0x3ffbad40 0x40093585:0x3ffbad60 0x40083e20:0x3ffbad80 0x40083e74:0x3ffbadb0 0x40093945:0x3ffbadd0 0x40083b51:0x3ffbadf0 0x40143387:0x3ffbae10 0x4014c0db:0x3ffbae30 0x401495f5:0x3ffbae50 0x4010f88b:0x3ffbae70
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> 
14:16:24.591 -> ELF file SHA256: 298482b5a443718c
14:16:24.629 -> 
14:16:24.662 -> Rebooting...
14:16:24.662 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
14:16:24.662 -> 
14:16:24.662 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
14:16:24.662 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
14:16:24.662 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
14:16:24.662 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
14:16:24.662 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
14:16:24.662 -> load:0x40078000,len:13964
14:16:24.662 -> load:0x40080400,len:3600
14:16:24.662 -> entry 0x400805f0

This is another way I tried to Publish the Image.
        Serial.print(F("\nSending camera1 val"));
        Serial.print(buffer.c_str());
        Serial.print("...");
        if(!camera1.publish(buffer.c_str())) {
          Serial.println(F("Failed"));
        } else {
          Serial.print(F("OK!"));
          lastMsg = now;
          buffer = "";
        }
        tripper = 2;
        Serial.print("tripped");
        Serial.print(tripper);
      }
    }
  }

And this is the crash log for it.
14:27:37.091 -> Buffer Length: 
14:27:37.091 -> 24168
14:27:37.308 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (InstructionFetchError). Exception was unhandled.
14:27:37.308 -> 
14:27:37.308 -> Core  0 register dump:
14:27:37.308 -> PC      : 0x3f400008  PS      : 0x00060b33  A0      : 0x80173770  A1      : 0x3ffcbb10  
14:27:37.308 -> A2      : 0x00000001  A3      : 0x2b456a70  A4      : 0x60033c00  A5      : 0x0180d423  
14:27:37.343 -> A6      : 0x00000005  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x801736bd  A9      : 0x3ffcbaf0  
14:27:37.343 -> A10     : 0x00000066  A11     : 0x00000004  A12     : 0x0000000c  A13     : 0x00000000  
14:27:37.343 -> A14     : 0x00060b20  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000020  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000002  
14:27:37.343 -> EXCVADDR: 0x3f400008  LBEG    : 0x40085a85  LEND    : 0x40085a8d  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> Backtrace: 0x3f400005:0x3ffcbb10 |<-CORRUPTED
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.377 -> ELF file SHA256: 31311647482da272
14:27:37.377 -> 
14:27:37.415 -> Rebooting...
14:27:37.415 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
14:27:37.415 -> 
14:27:37.415 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
14:27:37.415 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
14:27:37.415 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
14:27:37.453 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
14:27:37.453 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
14:27:37.453 -> load:0x40078000,len:13964
14:27:37.453 -> load:0x40080400,len:3600
14:27:37.453 -> entry 0x400805f0
14:27:38.254 -> *wm:AutoConnect 

This is the rest of the code after trying to Publish the Image
        else if((sliderval == 8)&&(tripper == 2)){
        cameratime = 2160000000;
        long now = millis();
        Serial.print (now);
        tripper = 1;
        Serial.print("tripped");
        Serial.print(tripper);
       
      }
    }
  }

  
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(F("\nSending wifi val "));
        Serial.print(z);
        Serial.print("...");
        if(!wifi.publish(z)) {
          Serial.println(F("Failed"));
        } else {
          Serial.println(F("OK"));
        }
    }
  }

Here is the Publish methods in Adafruit_MQTT.h
// Publish a message to a topic using the specified QoS level.  Returns true
  // if the message was published, false otherwise.
  bool publish(const char *topic, const char *payload, uint8_t qos = 0);
  bool publish(const char *topic, uint8_t *payload, uint16_t bLen,
               uint8_t qos = 0);

    uint16_t publishPacket(uint8_t *packet, const char *topic, uint8_t *payload,
                             uint16_t bLen, uint8_t qos);

class Adafruit_MQTT_Publish {
public:
  Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(Adafruit_MQTT *mqttserver, const char *feed,
                        uint8_t qos = 0);

  bool publish(const char *s);
  bool publish(
      double f,
      uint8_t precision =
          2); // Precision controls the minimum number of digits after decimal.
              // This might be ignored and a higher precision value sent.
  bool publish(int32_t i);
  bool publish(uint32_t i);
  bool publish(uint8_t *b, uint16_t bLen);

private:
  Adafruit_MQTT *mqtt;
  const char *topic;
  uint8_t qos;
};

It seems strange to me that Adafruit would provide for Publishing an Image and then not provide for that in thier library.
I have been able to Publish an Image to Adafruit using PubSubClient.h but I don't like it as well.
Anyone who can help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

Please run your code through a C++ code formatter. You can find them online on the web with a search engine. Your code is so erratically formatted it's virtually unreadable. Properly, consistently formatted code makes it much easier to follow what the code is doing.

You also seem to have mingled one of your crash dumps with some of the code. And the only useful piece of information for the second crash dump (the line similar to "Guru Meditation Error" in the first dump) you left out. Please edit the question and fix the mingled dump and missing message. Since you're sharing crash dumps they're almost useless unless you run them through the ESP Exception decoder, which only you can do. That will pinpoint where in the program it crashed, so again... edit the question and add that information.

Thanks! That's way more readable. You're much more likely to get help this way :)

I ran the code through a formatter and put the new code in.  I separated the code from the crash dump.  The "Guru Meditation Error" is in both crash dumps.  The last thing that happens before the crash is 'Serial.println(buffer.length); Serial.println("");'  The next thing to happen is to Publish the data to Adafruit 'Serial.print(F("\nSending camera1 val"));'  which is when the crash occurs.  I'm thinking this is because I do not have the Image Data formatted correctly.  I hope I have been helpful.  I may be able to do some tomorrow but I an leaving sunday to visit relatives.

unsigned int length(); is not a valid code, unsigned int length; is, but you are not using it and doesn't need it!

Thanks.  I was wondering how I would use this from the Adafruit_MQTT.h library to Publish the Image.  bool publish(const char *topic, const char *payload, uint8_t qos = 0);
